# sum the first m elements of an array

Tags: matlab

I have a array of length n. Is there function that allows me to calculate the partial sum of the first m elements of this array( m<=n )?

I thought of something like this

```
sum(X,1:10) %returns the sum of the 10 first elements of the array
```

but that doesn't work. Sum seems only to calculate whole columns, rows or higher dimensional equivalents.

Edit: What I was wondering if there is matlab function doing this - I could program one myself but there is a chance that it is slower and can do potentially weird things :)

My function looks like this:

```
function[sum] = partialSum(X,m)
sum = 0;
for i = 1:m
    sum = sum + X(i);
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want.  If it's just the sum of the first `m` elements, then it's this:

```
result = sum(X(1:m));
```

If you want the sequence of partial sums, then use [`cumsum()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) instead of `sum()`.